# Can't restore Nuget package

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have a solution with 10 projects, all using different versions of Newtonsoft.JSON dll stored locally on the system. Now that I need to use a Nuget package and do restore Nuget package, I get this error: 
[image: error]

I am unable to restore any nuget package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

11.0.0 isn't a valid version for Newtonsoft.Json. Pick a valid version to restore with.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 1):

There is no version 11.0.0 for Newtonsoft.Json available.

Try finding that package in your packages.config file and change the version 11.0.1

[image: packages.config]

[image: Newtonsoft config]